# Requesting some feedback on a "Declined" custom comment flag

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, moderation, comment-flags

Yesterday, I noticed an answer on a meta question:

> *"So what? <investment company> owns both of the companies. <link to a wiki page>"*

That's a non-answer posted by a user that's known for less than constructive Meta activity. The answer was deleted by community members. At that time, it had a score of `-20`.

Under that answer, there was a comment by a moderator:

> *"This is the root cause of the problem. Insightful. Shame people don't seem to realise this. Most activity is driven by greed, it takes a lot of effort to combat that, as it seems to be our species default setting."*

Naturally, they're free to have that opinion, but I find it odd that a representative of the site / community would encourage non-answers like that. So much so, that I decided to (custom-) flag the comment:

> In case you weren't aware: <username> is a known troll / conspiracy theorist that's usually unconstructive on Meta. I think it's a bad idea for a diamond to encourage him, especially on a non-answer. <sub><sup>(2019-05-14 07:26:26Z)</sup></sub>

Now, that flag was *declined*, and I'm curious why?
No comment has been added to the declination.

I understand that there isn't any "action" that could be taken from the comment / flag, but that wasn't the point of the flag. It was purely meant to raise awareness, possibly informing the moderator of something they didn't know yet.

- Shouldn't I have "voiced" my concerns in a private manner like that?
- If comment flags aren't the right way, how *do* I voice my concerns?
- Am I worrying too much, and does "declined" just mean they disagree with the comment flag?

Especially on a relatively low traffic site like Meta, I'd hoped to see some kind of explanation on a flag declination, even if it's a *"Nah, that was fine."*

Comment: Triggering such mayhem is usually the intention of users like that.  Curse of the Internet, you kinda fell for it.  Have you considered starting your own blog?

Comment: @HansPassant: From my point of view, I'd rather "fall for it" once, and possibly increase moderator awareness, than to see answers like that encouraged.

Comment: Flaging, IMHO, only make sense if there is some action you expect from moderators.

Comment: @BDL: In a sense, I'd expect moderators to have a (tiny) internal discussion. Does that count as action?

Comment: No, not really. Unless you want a moderator to drop a message to that user, just making moderators aware of something that doesn't directly require their attention is just noise. But let's wait for moderators to reply and state how they see it.

Comment: From the answer: _"in future if you wish to provide private feedback to moderators, please use custom post flags instead."_ Apparently, moderators can not leave feedback on comment flags.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Now, that flag was declined, and I'm curious why?
>
> Am I worrying too much, and does "declined" just mean they disagree with the *comment* flag?

Moderators (including staff) **cannot leave feedback on comment flags** (unlike post flags) - only delete, edit, or dismiss them. To mark comment flags helpful, we have to either delete or edit the comment.

A CM reviewed the flag and didn't see any reason to delete the flagged comment, so it was dismissed (this is displayed as "declined" in your flag history). In other words, avoid flagging comments if they probably do not require deletion (or editing).

Also: don't worry too much about this, declined comment flags do not impact your flagging ability. Whether the comment was deleted or dismissed, all declined custom comment flags were still manually reviewed by mods and at least one moderator would have taken note of its contents.

> It was purely meant to raise awareness, possibly informing the moderator of something they didn't know yet.
>
> Shouldn't I have "voiced" my concerns in a private manner like that?
>
> If *comment* flags aren't the right way, how do I voice my concerns?

While your concerns are appreciated, in future if you wish to provide private feedback to moderators, please **use custom post flags** instead. Moderators can leave a response on post flags if necessary, or just mark post flags helpful without having to delete any content.

Another good reason to use post flags to contact moderators is that post flags don't get automatically marked helpful when the post itself gets deleted. Comment flags however, get marked helpful when the author or other trusted users delete the post, and moderators will not see your comment flag on that post in the mod flag queue.

Comment: Didn't I read somewhere that (even custom) comment flags get auto-accepted when the post gets deleted? If yes, are those flags still manually reviewed by a mod?

Comment: @AndréKool you're right, this is still the case. thanks for the reminder

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @SamuelLiew. I wasn't aware of that difference between comment / post flags. The answer was already deleted before I flagged the comment, so that's why it wasn't auto-accepted.